# Counting the number of distinct values in one column

Tags: sql, oracle, count

```
with table1 as
(
  select CTN_MAIN, SUBS_KEY, BAN_KEY, count(CTN_MAIN) as c
  from 
  (
    select distinct CTN_MAIN, SUBS_KEY, BAN_KEY
    from STG_SDB_LOAD SDB
  )
)select * from table1;
```

I'm trying to get this 3 columns CTN_MAIN, SUBS_KEY, BAN_KEY and the number of times a distinct CTN_MAIN appears. If I do just

```
select count(CTN_MAIN)
```

I get the count main field, but I need other columns as well. What can I do?

the error is

```
ORA-00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
with table1 as
(
  select CTN_MAIN, SUBS_KEY, BAN_KEY, count(CTN_MAIN) as c
  from 
  (
    select distinct CTN_MAIN, SUBS_KEY, BAN_KEY
    from STG_SDB_LOAD SDB
  ) group by CTN_MAIN, SUBS_KEY, BAN_KEY
)select * from table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use analytical function

```
with table1 as
(
  select CTN_MAIN, SUBS_KEY, BAN_KEY, COUNT(DISTINCT CTN_MAIN) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL) as c
  from 
  (
    select distinct CTN_MAIN, SUBS_KEY, BAN_KEY
    from STG_SDB_LOAD SDB
  )
)select * from table1;
```